# Is Python 3.7.4 missing compatibility EXE files on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I haven't used Python in a while, and only in Linux. Now on Windows, and just installed 3.7.4. I noticed immediately that python3.exe is not in the install directory, nor any of the pythonX.x.exe files, that are used for compatibility. I can only access Python through "python" from my command prompt, and old scripts that use Python 3 won't work.

Is there something I am missing here?

Of course, I can solve this for now by using symlinks, but is this an error in 3.7.4, or more likely, have I done something wrong in setting up my environment on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong. This is just how Python is on Windows. There's the [`py` launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) too that might help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

3.2 The Microsoft Store Package

All three commands are also available with version number suffixes, for example, **as python3.exe and python3.x.exe as well as python.exe (where 3.x is the specific version you want to launch, such as 3.7).**

Virtual environments can be created with python -m venv and activated and used as normal.

If you have installed another version of Python and added it to your PATH variable, **it will be available as python.exe rather than the one from the Microsoft Store. To access the new installation, use python3.exe or python3.x.exe.**

Comment: FYI: I ran into this issue after installing 3.7.4 from https://www.python.org. I have not installed  the MS version and from Git Bash on windows symlinks from  "installdir"/python.exe -> "installdir"/python3.exe did not solve the problem